# Creating a custom input with Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I want to create my own set of HTML Elements with Web Components, which all include some basic functionality.
I wanted to start with an input and it seems like there are two possibilities:
Either inherit from `HTMLElement` or from `HTMLInputElement`.

Option A :

```
class BasicCustomHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
  //basic functionality
}

class CustomInput extends BasicCustomHTMLElement {
  let shadow = this.attachShadow({
    mode: 'open'
  });

  let textbox = document.createElement("input");
  shadow.appendChild(textbox);
}
```

Option B

```
class CustomInput extends HTMLInputElement {

}
```

My problem with Option B ist, that I do not have a main `class`, where I can define basic functionality. On the other hand I have to rewrite Code in Option A for functionality that the native input and select elements offer.

Are there some aspects I am overlooking?

Comment: You could define a separate helper class and use it in the Custom Input obect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that you can't combine option A and option B so that you extend from `HTMLInputElement` initially with a base class and then extend that with more specific classes later.

```
class BasicCustomHTMLElement extends HTMLInputElement {
}

class CustomInput extends BasicCustomHTMLElement {
}
```

If you want a shared set of features to extend a number of built-in classes with you can use [mixins](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/).

```
const BaseClassMixin = (superclass) => class extends superclass {
};

class CustomInput extends BaseClassMixin(HTMLInputElement) {
}

class CustomTextArea extends BaseClassMixin(HTMLTextAreaElement) {
}
```

However, currently [only Chrome supports extending built-in elements](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4670146924773376) so it is not recommended for real-world use.

Comment: The website would run inside an embedded Chromium browser. Running on "normal" browser is planned in 1 year. Do you think I should still avoid extending native built-in elements?

Comment: Actually Firefox implements them too. Only Safari doesn't intend to do it

Comment: My point was that I want to use the base class not only for inputs, but also for labels, textareas, selects etc.

Comment: Safari has said they will never ship it so in theory if you want to support Safari you can't extend built-in elements. Although you might have some luck using [polyfills](https://medium.com/@WebReflection/extending-built-in-elements-9dce404b75b4).

Comment: I've added an example of using mixins.

Comment: @abraham Thank you for adding an example. The blog post you linked says somthing about a framework. Is you example vanilla javascript?